# Access to data values inside itself in vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How can i access to data values inside itself in `vue.js`?

Code:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        foo: 123,
        bar: this.foo
    }
}
```

In this case I got `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options I see:

```
data: function(){
    const data = {
        foo: 123
    };

    data.bar = data.foo;

    return data;
}
```

or

```
data: function(){
    const data = {
        foo: 123
    };

    return {
        ...data,
        bar: data.foo
    };
}
```

You've got `undefined` because of `this.foo` refers to `function(){``s context, not object`s context.